# configuring my code to append to child instead of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code I [wrote](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrVQYr)
Currently it uses innerHTML to write to the page with a forloop. However, I noticed that instead of writing everything. It just writes the last element in the array.

I searched and saw that I have to use the DOM to get this done as innerHTML will ALWAYS destroy instead of replacing. So I wrote this

```
function print(message) {    
var mydiv = document.getElementById("box");
    mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
}
```

To go inside my code and replace the innerHTML line. However, this doesn't seem to work. Can anybody help me getting it running?

by "this doesn't seem to work" i mean that the code won't append to the child of box. so my text will not be inserted into the element with the 'box' ID.
What i want to happen is just like in my codepen where i used innerHTML but instead of each only the last element in the array showing up, i want them all to show up

edit:
okay updated the codepen. seems the code I posted on this page kinda works. but it doesn't seem to go in the right place. if you check the codepen and add some text and scroll down you can see it doesn't fit into place

Comment: "this doesn't seem to work" can you explain in more detail what does not work?

Comment: message comes from the print function. that code will site inside of my print function. "function print(message)" you can see it inside the codepen. i'll edit to make it more clear

Comment: i edited my post a little more. hopefully it's more clear

Comment: mm for me it adds `<span>text</span>` to the div if i open your pen copy your code and press run.

Comment: why are you not trying jquery for doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the print function in this way:

```
function print(message) {
   var html =  document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = html + message;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwBOdq

Comment: Quote from OP: *Currently it uses innerHTML to write to the page with a forloop. However, I noticed that instead of writing everything. It just writes the last element in the array. I searched and saw that I have to use the DOM to get this done as innerHTML will ALWAYS destroy instead of replacing.* This much was true.

Comment: unfortunately, the same thing happens. only the last element in the array gets put out to the page. instead of all of them

Comment: whoa that seems to work @Draykos !! awesome thank you!